# How to create an UI similar to the attached image?

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create an UI just like the attached image!

[image]

How do we create these types of UI? Is it a `ListView`? And how do we get the arrow button on the right hand side? How should I start with such kind of layouts?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with a `LinearLayout` too.

Have that `LinearLayout`s orientation be `vertical`. Create such *list items* (it isn't related to ListView) using `RelativeLayout`.

Have the icon be an `ImageView` aligned to its parent left and vertically centered, the text would be a normal `TextView` which is to the right of that icon and vertically centered as well and finally another `ImageView` but this time aligned to its parents right and vertically centered.

These is the receipt.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ListView, you should learn how to write your own ArrayAdapter and returns in the getView method the View you want to be each row of the ListView.

Comment: Why do you think this should be a listview? I mean you are not trying to display data here, it's just a bunch (fixed) of styled buttons.

Comment: Hmm.. true, maybe ins't. So it's just a composed layout.

Answer (score 0):

AnDroidDraw lets you create the layout online and then later download it on your device. http://www.droiddraw.org/

Create appropriate custom ArrayAdapter for this layout.